# Commands for ImageMagick to create thumbnails

Tags: image, image-processing, image-manipulation, imagemagick

Given an photograph uploaded by a user, what is best approach to creating a number various sized thumbnails Using ImageMagick (or GraphicsMagick)? My guess to the steps:

1. Create a super sample of the image, maintaining original aspect ratio
2. Apply watermark to super sample
3. Create the various sized thumbnails using the watermarked super sampled image

Additional requirements:

1. Best quality possible (does this mean PNG over JPG?)
2. Smallest file size possible (does this mean JPG over PNG?)
3. Use density of 72x72, units is ppi

Since I am not that familiar with the intricacies of IM (or GM), some guidance to the best commands that meet my objectives would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the ImageMagick documentation:

- For a specific size http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#fit
- For watermarks http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#watermarking

The best quality possible is complicated since difference images compress differently. I'm partial to PNG since it has a variety if compression techniques available to allow for experimentation.

Comment: I'm familiar with the basic commands. As a matter of fact, I can already do what I need to do. The problem is that I am not sure if my approach is the best. There are so many options to ImageMagick.

Comment: I'd suggest using the commands recommended in the docs, since they're known to work. Supersampling an image for scaling down is largely pointless.

Comment: Better to put those commands here, as it's a headache to read that documentation.